# How to Brew Install SQLite3 FTS5 extension?

Tags: sqlite, homebrew

Is there an easy way to enable the FTS5 extension for SQLite3 installed with Brew? Some older posts say there should be an install option `--with-fts5`, however:

```
$ brew reinstall sqlite3 --with-fts5
...
Error: invalid option: --with-fts5
```

The `fts3_tokenizer` is not enabled. I assume there must be an easy way to install/enabled the extension with Brew without compiling from source outside of Brew.

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.35.5 2021-04-19 18:32:05
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .dbconfig
          defensive off
            dqs_ddl on
            dqs_dml on
        enable_fkey off
        enable_qpsg off
     enable_trigger on
        enable_view on
     fts3_tokenizer off
 legacy_alter_table off
 legacy_file_format off
     load_extension on
   no_ckpt_on_close off
     reset_database off
        trigger_eqp off
     trusted_schema on
    writable_schema off

$ brew info sqlite3
sqlite: stable 3.35.5 (bottled) [keg-only]
Command-line interface for SQLite
https://sqlite.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.35.5 (11 files, 4.2MB)
  Built from source on 2021-05-18 at 08:54:33
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/sqlite.rb
...
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>Try to use CFLAGS environment:</del>

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5" brew reinstall sqlite
```

Edited:

Rebuild to enable fts5 is unnecessary. The sqlite 3.35.5 package is already fts5 module enabled.

```
$ brew fetch sqlite
...
$ tar xzf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/61d40ad2021e894bcf4c7475eea2dbbfee14c4426b1bbb1816c4055ad1c70b50--sqlite--3.35.5.catalina.bottle.tar.gz -O sqlite/3.35.5/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib \
  | strings - | grep '^fts5: 20\|trigram'
trigram
fts5: 2021-04-19 18:32:05 1b256d97b553a9611efca188a3d995a2fff712759044ba480f9a0c9e98fae886
```

Comment: `brew` provides pre-compiled release, `CFLAGS` does nothing unless you use `brew install --build-from-source` to build from source.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you on the trac mailing list too but will post here too.

If you check https://sqlite.org/fts5.html there seems to be a option `--enable-fts5` but it also seems disabled by the fault. That said they point to a " amalgamation" (there is a link to it in the page) where you can use this option if you compile the " amalgamation".

Markus

Comment: I have not yet found a way to pass the `--enable-fts5` option to Homebrew.

Comment: maybe you take a look at this link https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/352928 it states too to edit the install script and shows an example. Again i dont use homebrew so i can't test that.

Answer (score 0):

FTS5 is enabled. I was mistaken about the source of the problem I'm experiencing.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> import pprint
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> cursor = db.execute('PRAGMA COMPILE_OPTIONS')
>>> pprint.pprint(cursor.fetchall())
[(u'BUG_COMPATIBLE_20160819',),
 (u'COMPILER=clang-12.0.5',),
 (u'DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=2000',),
 (u'DEFAULT_CKPTFULLFSYNC',),
 (u'DEFAULT_JOURNAL_SIZE_LIMIT=32768',),
 (u'DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=4096',),
 (u'DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS=2',),
 (u'DEFAULT_WAL_SYNCHRONOUS=1',),
 (u'ENABLE_API_ARMOR',),
 (u'ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA',),
 (u'ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB',),
 (u'ENABLE_FTS3',),
 (u'ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS',),
 (u'ENABLE_FTS3_TOKENIZER',),
 (u'ENABLE_FTS4',),
 (u'ENABLE_FTS5',),
 (u'ENABLE_JSON1',),
 (u'ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=1',),
 (u'ENABLE_PREUPDATE_HOOK',),
 (u'ENABLE_RTREE',),
 (u'ENABLE_SESSION',),
 (u'ENABLE_SNAPSHOT',),
 (u'ENABLE_SQLLOG',),
 (u'ENABLE_STMT_SCANSTATUS',),
 (u'ENABLE_UNKNOWN_SQL_FUNCTION',),
 (u'ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT',),
 (u'HAS_CODEC_RESTRICTED',),
 (u'HAVE_ISNAN',),
 (u'MAX_LENGTH=2147483645',),
 (u'MAX_MMAP_SIZE=1073741824',),
 (u'MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=500000',),
 (u'OMIT_AUTORESET',),
 (u'OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION',),
 (u'STMTJRNL_SPILL=131072',),
 (u'THREADSAFE=2',),
 (u'USE_URI',)]
```